# Spring WebFlux WebClient: can't catch exception

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-webflux

I'm establishing connection to external microservice with Spring's Reactive WebClient. In the scenario planned, this microservice could be totally unaccessible or refuse connections.

**The goal is:** I want to handle connection errors by raising appropriate exception and handling it then. The code in general just makes external HTTP URL call and writes the result in Mono variable

**The problem is:** I'm unable to catch errors, when it comes. Execution flow never reaches the catch block. Please, help me to understand what I did wrong.

The part of my code is:

```
Mono<String> result;
try {
    result = webClient.get()
            .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder.path("/users/validate")
                    .queryParam("token", authHeaderSearch)
                    .build())
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(String.class)
            .onErrorResume(Exception.class, throwable -> Mono.error(new CantValidateTokenException("")))
    ;

    result
        .onErrorResume(Exception.class, throwable -> Mono.error(new CantValidateTokenException("")))
        .subscribe(e -> log.info("Token check result is: " + e))
    ;

} catch (Exception e) {
 //some code there
}
```

The full code is here:
https://pastecode.io/s/9fceicf1

The exceptions i'm getting:

```
io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: /[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:80
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

And my custom exception is raised too, but I can't catch it

```
reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented: com.decode.msapp.apigw.exceptions.CantValidateTokenException: 
Caused by: com.decode.msapp.apigw.exceptions.CantValidateTokenException: 
    at com.decode.msapp.apigw.config.AuthFilter.lambda$apply$2(AuthFilter.java:67) ~
```

Comment: dont think try/catch will work here. You need to do something with onXXXError in your reactive chain. If you want for example catch your exception and show message to gui or whatever it is you propably need some reactive custom exception handler that can do that.

Comment: you cannot catch it here because it's outside of the scope. reactor runs processing in a different thread